# Using IWImage in Delphi Intraweb

Tags: delphi, intraweb

I'm new to Intraweb, so using Delphi how to just display a simple image on a form using IWImage? if I try to load an image through the picture property.

I  got this error 'Cannot assign a TdxPNGImage to a TPngImage'.

[image]

Comment: What steps, *exactly*, triggered the exception? Please copy - paste error messages as text and not as images.

Comment: Nothing much, First just start new Intraweb project then add IWImage1 and set it's picture property to any image from your drive that's it, u will c the image in the design view fine but when u run the project it will raise this error.

Comment: Nope, It works ok for me (using a .png from my hdd). Design view OK, Run time OK. Why does your error message speak about `TdxPNGImage`?

Comment: I don't know, but which version u r using ? because long time ago in Delphi XE things were ok however on berlin things started to be strange

Comment: I use Delphi 10.1 Berlin (on Windows 7) and Google Chrome. Please show the minimal code with which we can reproduce the problem, iow an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I'm afraid your question will start to collect downvotes otherwise.

Comment: It might be that the IW component doesn't support the file extension of that image.

Comment: #Tom You were right about TdxPNGImage, it was a component I've installed that missed up with intraweb  configurations, I've uninstalled it and things works fine. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

So I have two guesses.

1. You're using a very old and outdated version of IntraWeb and Delphi.
2. You installed some third-party component or suite that messed up some IntraWeb related stuff.

Either way. It works fine for me. Here is how to add an image via code to the `TIWImage` component:

```
  IWImage1.Picture.LoadFromFile('C:\Development\Samples\Data\cus2.bmp');
```

You can also load the image in design-time by simply going to the Object Inspector and double-clicking on the `Picture` property, then choose your image as shown below:
[image]